# Replace UITableView and UITableViewController with Three20

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20

Hi i have a working **UITableViewController** and **UITableView** with custom cells but i want to add some async functionality from Three20, so i would like to migrate my current classes to the ones from **Three20**, **TTTableViewController** and **TTTableViewController**, to use the TTImageView inside of my custom cell.
The functionality would be download asynchronously an image for an imageView.
Apart from these i want the cache func.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why switch to Three20 for this? Why not just use the async functionality already present in the system, and use something like `NSCache` for caching your images you download? What you suggest you want to do smells real bad for what your end goal is.

Comment: Ok the reason im doing this is that what ive done is a really messy mix of libraries and snippets, so i thought it would be nicer to set it up based on one only library, and for what i need and plan to add in the future, three20 is prefect. thanks for the reply

Comment: Ah well then, best of luck. I won't touch Three20 with a 10 foot pole.

Comment: Wow, thats not much encouraging.. Which library would you recommend?

Comment: Three20 is actually really good but has some limitations. Have you considered Sensible TableView?

Comment: I recommend libraries that mesh well with the design principals of the underlying frameworks that build the system. This way, reuse is at its highest -- these libraries need not implement their own versions of basic controls if they provide no additional functionality, because of design decisions made throughout their system. Three20 unfortunately, fails in this respect.

Comment: Yes I get your point, and that is exactly why im having trouble adding it to my project, but well this functionalities are important to my app. anyway, if it continues to get me trouble im gonna make my own. thanks